# Is there any SQL database which has a provider optimizing network communications so that columns repeated in many rows are sent only once to a client?

Tags: sql, optimization, database-connection, query-optimization

Considering multitude of SQL databases on the market and each having it's own providers which send the data over the wire in a custom way which means freedom of implementation, are the databases optimizing columns which values are constant for many consecutive rows so that value for a column is sent only once per group/per value change?

Since SQL engine can possibly have the information which columns will not change in the result set - why would these be sent more than once per group?

Simple example:

[Species] Table

```
Id  GroupId Name
1   1       Goat
2   1       Horse
3   1       Donkey
4   2       Pine
```

[Groups] Table

```
Id  Kingdom Description
1   Animals This is a very long description of animals group
2   Plants  This is ever longer description of plants group
```

Now following query:

```
SELECT s.*, g.Kingdom, g.Description FROM Species s JOIN Groups g ON g.Id = s.GroupId
```

will return:

```
Id  GroupId Name    Kingdom Description
1   1       Goat    Animals This is a very long description of animals group
2   1       Horse   Animals This is a very long description of animals group
3   1       Donkey  Animals This is a very long description of animals group
4   2       Pine    Plants  This is ever longer description of plants group
```

Implementation of such RLE-like encoding will be trivial even without going into DB engine level - just holding previous row when sending and receiving and having a "USE PREVIOUS" value pasted for one or more columns.

I got the idea for this question when I needed to join a table containing long BLOB-like field which can appear more than once in a result set; I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

My question is are there any databases doing similar optimizations in their providers? My thought was that it was always up to a user to build queries so that rows won't contain duplicate information but when multiple queries are made we have another problem of going through a whole client - server pipeline again.

Comment: I doubt it.  The result set has no ordering, unless a query has an `order by`.  There are ways you can accomplish something similar by encoding the results as JSON or XML.

Comment: This is up to your architecture, not the DBMS.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, order by is one example when such grouping would be practical. Joined table columns can cause implicit ordering as well and in some of these cases such encoding of query result would cause significant decrease in bandwidth usage and possibly in processing time.

Comment: @paqogomez It's only partially up to architecture because there is no control over inner implementation of a DB provider which can be optimized transparently to a user.

Comment: @too . . . I don't know what you mean by "joined table columns can cause implicit ordering."  Repeat three times:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  And results sets are unordered, unless there is an explicit `order by` in the outermost level of the query.  No ambiguiity here.  That's how relational databases work.

Comment: I cant see how it would decrease processing time.  Even if you dehydrated the data before it went over the wire, you still have to hydrate it afterwards.  I would suggest that if you are pushing that much duplicate data over the wire that it slows you down, then you have other problems and this one is just theoretical.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What I mean the result set can be partially ordered based on inner workings of the DB engine query optimizer, for a client it is still unordered. In the end there are many queries with same row values for certain columns repeated in a result set and this is the room for optimization. With explicit ORDER BY there is even better chance of getting less data transferred through a wire wit a relatively simple provider change.

Comment: @paqogomez When row buffer is rebuilt in the client provider and passed on to the client, references to previous strings can be passed instead of copying so there will be less time spent on copying if value is repeated. Obviously this can go wrong if implemented in a bad way.

Comment: Great idea..sounds like you need to start writing a driver.

Comment: @paqogomez Sarcasm intended? :)

Comment: I'm only being sarcastic if you are.  I know of no such driver, if you have the idea.. then get writing.  The world needs more and better software.